# Mapper Reducer not increasing from zero in HIVE select query

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Hi i have 32 millions of records in one of my HIVE integrated with HBase table .
When i try to do simple select query it give me below reading .

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/hadoop/user/Item.txt'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
select * from hbase_table ;

Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2016-11-09 10:48:11,767 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-11-09 10:49:12,206 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 51.67 sec
2016-11-09 10:50:12,536 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 101.52 sec
2016-11-09 10:51:12,861 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 124.31 sec
2016-11-09 10:52:13,172 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 144.26 sec
2016-11-09 10:53:13,472 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 163.76 sec
```

Comment: Try check Resource Manager UI about the status of this job.

Answer (score 0):

The reduce percent will be zero because the output of the mappers will be directly written in local path .

Check yarn web UI for resource availability.
In hive prompt `set mapreduce.job.maps = x;`
Then run above command

Comment: I have set set mapreduce.job.maps =44;
but then getting only 6 mapper running and repeating same thing 2016-11-10 01:02:29,199 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-11-10 01:03:30,044 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 314.46 sec
2016-11-10 01:04:30,585 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 609.4 sec

Comment: can you share the yarn web UI